# Application crashes when activity starts

Tags: android, android-activity

My android project crashes when I try to move from one class to another, and I always get the same error. I have possibly removed some files when I was adding external some jars.

Here is my LogCat:

```
W/dalvikvm(306): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(306): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=HERE IS MY PACKAGE NAME/.HERE IS MY ACTIVITY } from ProcessRecord{4502a000 306:MY PACKAGENAME/10042} (pid=306, uid=10042) requires android.permission.INTERNET
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1298)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  atMY PACKAGENAME. $1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:66)
: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process(306): Sending signal. PID: 306 SIG: 9
```

(Those package and activity names are not the one I use)

All of my applications in Eclipse crash with quite similar LogCat messages. Does anyone know what is wrong?
The project also does not launch from the menu or my phone. When I try to do so, it says that the application is not installed on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to add "internet" permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android.permission.INTERNET E/AndroidRuntime(306): at
```

For example:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Q: I have allready added the internet permision under application in the manifest.  A: Sorry, but your Logcat clearly shows you're getting a "Permission denied INTERNET E/AndroidRuntime" when you try to read a "Parcel" in your "Instrumentation" activity.  Please double-check your AndroidManifest.xml!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `INTERNET` permission in your Manifest. Logcat clearly says that.

Comment: I have allready added the internet permision under application in the manifest.