# Android Service that searches in a website

Tags: android, service

This is my very first thread so please bear with me. :)

I want to create an Android Service that searches a specific string on a website. To do this I have tried to download that site and search within the html code but the application always crashes when trying to download it.

Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code with your logcat.

Comment: It could be lack of permissions, try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593647/application-crashes-when-activity-starts

Comment: have you added the service to the Manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similer problem when i started making an android app that scans imdb.com for movie information. After a lot of searching the internet and testing things out i came up with this:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

URL url = new URL("websiteToLookAt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);

String lineThatIsBeingRead = null;
String theString;

while((lineThatIsBeingRead = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

    if(lineThatIsBeingRead.contains("StringYouAreLookingFor")){
        theString = lineThatIsBeingRead;
        break;
    }
}
```

- **The first line** sets up the URL of the website you are scanning
- **The second line** opens a the internet to allow you to access the html source directly
- **The third line** makes a Buffered reader that is able to read the source the InputStreamReader gives it
- **The fifth line** is the string that the current line of HTML source is being held in while the buffered reader is checking if it contains the right string. (string1.contains(string2)  looks at wether or not string2 is in string1. example: `String myName = "john";` if you were to test if `myName.contains("oh");` it would return true)
- **The Sixth line** is the string that you will put the string you are looking for from the HTML source(like if you were looking for the name of a movie, this would be the string you would assign the name to)
- **The while loop** reads the next line of the html source code every time the loop starts over and sets the line it just read to the String variable *lineThatIsBeingRead*. it will keep doing this as long as there is a new line to read. When the buffered reader comes to the end of the HTML source the conditions for the while loop return false and it breaks the loop.
- **The if statment** checks to see if *lineThatIsBeingRead* has the string *StringYouAreLookingFor* in it. if it does, it sets theString(the string you are looking for) to *lineThatIsBeingRead*(the string that is in the buffered reader) then it breaks the while loop. otherwise, it resets the while loop and it starts all over again.

I have the variable *theString* in there because i was looking for several strings, but if you only need to find one string you can delete lines 6 & 11 and just have *lineThatIsBeingRead* as the string you assign the string you are looking for to.

Another thing to keep in mind is java doesn't allow you to connect to the internet through the UI thread(the way java wants you to do it is with an intent so when you publish the app remember to take this out and make it run on an intent). but if you add

```
if(BuildVERSION.SDK_INT >= 9){
    StrickMode.ThreadPolicy Policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(Policy);
}
```

to the onCreate() method and it will bypass that rule.

Hope this was helpful, and good luck with your project!